# Last value is incremented / decremented while click previous list item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am developing an app which is similar to Shopping cart. Here I am using BaseAdapter to populate cart data. There are,

3 ListItems:

Row 1

Row 2

Row 3

When I click increase / decrease button of Row 1 / Row 2, cart item count of the Row 3 is increased / decreased respectively. And I need to calculate TotalSum of the all the product.

Here is my code. Please check it and help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class CartCountBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context con;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ArproductMap;
    String MYFRAGMENT;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;


    public CartCountBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arproductMap, String myfragment) {
        this.con = context;
        this.ArproductMap = arproductMap;
        this.MYFRAGMENT = myfragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ArproductMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null);
        }


        viewHolder.addTowish = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addTowish);
        viewHolder.remove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove);

        viewHolder.cartProduct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartProduct);
        viewHolder.cartQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartQuantity);
        viewHolder.cartCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartCount);
        viewHolder.cartPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartPrice);
        viewHolder.cartPriceDum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartPriceDum);

        viewHolder.ivDecrease = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDecrease);
        viewHolder.ivIncrease = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIncrease);

        viewHolder.cardView = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_item);

        if (MYFRAGMENT == "CheckOutFragment") {
            viewHolder.addTowish = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addTowish);
            viewHolder.remove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            viewHolder.addTowish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.cardView.setCardElevation(0);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            viewHolder.cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        int CARTPRICE = Integer.parseInt(ArproductMap.get(position).get("Hash_Cart_Price"));
        viewHolder.cartProduct.setText(ArproductMap.get(position).get("Hash_Product_Name"));
        viewHolder.cartQuantity.setText(ArproductMap.get(position).get("Hash_Cart_Category"));
        viewHolder.cartCount.setText(ArproductMap.get(position).get("Hash_Cart_Quantity"));
        viewHolder.cartPrice.setText(String.valueOf(CARTPRICE));
        viewHolder.cartPriceDum.setText(String.valueOf(CARTPRICE));

        viewHolder.Quantity = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.cartCount.getText().toString());

        viewHolder.addTowish.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.remove.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewHolder.ivDecrease.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.ivIncrease.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.ivDecrease.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.ivIncrease.setOnClickListener(this);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ivIncrease:
                viewHolder.Quantity++;
                viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");

                break;

            case R.id.ivDecrease:
                viewHolder.Quantity--;
                if (viewHolder.Quantity <= 0) {
                    viewHolder.Quantity = 0;
                    viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");
                } else {
                    viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView cartProduct,
                cartQuantity,
                cartCount,
                cartPrice,
                cartPriceDum;

        int Quantity;
        ImageView ivDecrease;
        ImageView ivIncrease;
        Button addTowish;
        Button remove;
        CardView cardView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never put any data in your view holder. Put data in any data type like Arraylist. then get the position in your on click and based on that position modify the data

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ivIncrease:
            int position  = (int) v.getTag
            datalist[position]++;
            viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");

            break;

        case R.id.ivDecrease:
            int position  = (int) v.getTag
            datalist[position]++;
            if (viewHolder.Quantity <= 0) {
                viewHolder.Quantity = 0;
                viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");
            } else {
                viewHolder.cartCount.setText(viewHolder.Quantity + "");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Also if you want to make any view related changes put your onclick interface inside viewholder class then use this object